# drawRect does not resize and runs off screen 3.5 inch screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, drawrect

I'm using a draw rect to draw rectangle with a corner radius. The code works perfectly. When viewed on a 4inch screen you see the rectangle. When viewed on a 3.5inch screen the rectangle does not resize and runs off the bottom of the screen. Any pointers?

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGRect rrect = CGRectMake(20, 30, 280, 515);
    CGFloat radius = 7;

    CGFloat minx = CGRectGetMinX(rrect), midx = CGRectGetMidX(rrect), maxx = CGRectGetMaxX(rrect);
    CGFloat miny = CGRectGetMinY(rrect), midy = CGRectGetMidY(rrect), maxy = CGRectGetMaxY(rrect);

    // Start at 1
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, minx, midy);
    // Add an arc through 2 to 3
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, minx, miny, midx, miny, radius);
    // Add an arc through 4 to 5
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, maxx, miny, maxx, midy, radius);
    // Add an arc through 6 to 7
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, maxx, maxy, midx, maxy, radius);
    // Add an arc through 8 to 9
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, minx, maxy, minx, midy, radius);

    // Close the path
    CGContextClosePath(context);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 255, 255, 255, 1.0);

    // Fill & stroke the path
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);

}
```

Comment: Why would the rect resize when you are using hard numbers for the size?  If you want it to resize then base the width and height off of the screen dimensions (or better yet, the view dimensions that you are drawing in).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CGRect rrect = CGRectMake(20, 30, 280, 515);
```

This is the problem. You draw your rectangle with a height of 515 starting at an offset of 20, while your screen is not that long. Try using the frame of your view to draw instead of hardcoded values

```
CGRect rrect = CGRectMake(20, 30, self.frame.size.width - 20*2, self.frame.size.height - 30*2);
```